# How do i bring a DrawableAd to front

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, ads

I am inserting advertising on a windows phone 7 app.
this is where i create the drawable add:

```
AdComponent.Initialize("test_client");
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle rect = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle(0, 0, 480, 80);
//rect.Location= (20,20);
drawableAd = AdComponent.Current.CreateAd("Image480_80", rect, true);
drawableAd.AdRefreshed += new EventHandler(drawableAd_AdRefreshed);
drawableAd.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Advertising.AdErrorEventArgs>(drawableAd_ErrorOccurred);
```

and this is where i draw it on the OnDraw method:

```
AdComponent.Current.Draw();
```

what i am trying to do is make it come to the front, because i draw other components on the  OnDraw method and even though i draw the add in the end, it still goes behind all the other components

Comment: I know xna has different drawing orders.. have you tried drawing this first?

Comment: Please add your answer below as an answer, and not just an edit to the question.  That way you can select it as correct and close this out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out, i was drawing it inside the `spriteBatch`  together with the other components when in fact you have to draw it after the `spriteBatch.End();` thanks for the help anyway